# how to remove sql developer - 21.2.1.204.1703 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: uninstall, oracle, sqldeveloper

i installed sqldeveloper-21.2.1.204.1703-no-jre.zip

and now i cant remove it

i tried using sudo apt remove sqldeveloper

this error come up :E: Unable to locate package sqldeveloper

Comment: Why do you expect apt remove to work when you did not install it using apt? Please find the readme.txt or install.txt or the uninstall.txt or uninstall.sh in the directory you unzipped this. There will be one of those. I would expect you need to "rm" the direcotory since you unpacked a zip, you did not install that zip.  Maybe the contents of it and if so: find the file inside the zip.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Rinzwind 's comment on your question, this did the job for me:

```
sudo find / -name "*sqldeveloper*" -type d -exec rm -vR {} \;
```

You can even do it in two steps if you wanna make sure you're not deleting folders you might need (e.g university folders, ...) :

- step 1: `sudo find / -name "*sqldeveloper*" -type d`

This allows you to see all of the folders with the name "sqldeveloper" in it, you can even precise how deep should the find command search using `-maxdepth N` where N is the maximum level of depth it will go to (exp: 3).

- step 2: Remove them one by one manually using :

`rm -vR /the_path_of_the_folder_to_remove`

---

> apt remove sqldeveloper

does not work because sqldeveloper is installed by being unzipped, and not using `apt-get install` .